# What happens when 2 servers disconnect from each other and then reconnect?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We have 2 servers with a peer, orderer and kafka each. They are connected in the same channel, both have a chaincode installed and instantiated and the policy is one organization or the other.

Imagine that the internet goes down and they disconnect:

- Would both work individually?
- Can the write new transactions to the ledger?
- What would happen with the new submited blocks in the ledger when the internet goes up and running? How do this new blocks synchronize?

Thanks

EDIT1:

See image for clarification:
[image: 2 orgs with 1 server connected]

How would the network syncrhonize If during the disconnection both write to the ledger, how are those new generated blocks react? One gets invalidated? Or both are valid?

Answer (score 0):

The peers once disconnected won't receive keep alive from the channel peers and will keep throwing the same if you have debug logging enabled.

The peer won't lose any config even though it got disconnected from network. The discovery service in fabric takes care of finding the peers configured in the channel. So, Once the connection resumes it will automatically re-synchronize with the peers with gossip messages.

The peers can then write and read from ledger as usual.

Comment: But the peers still see the orderer that is on the server. So, will they still write?

Comment: I don't understand, is the orderer not on a different server? If the orderer and peer have a connection between them and the endorsement policy is satisfied by the peer then sure, you can write to the ledger in absence of the other disconnected peer.

Comment: Added image for clarification. Btw, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to consider here:

1) When you use a Kafka-based orderer, you will have to cluster the Kafka brokers if you expect them to be part of the same ordering service.  Kafka is used to distribute the messages to the ordering nodes.  If your Kafka brokers are not in a cluster, then you will have separate ordering services.  Recall that Kafka also requires Zookeeper as well.   Zookeeper has a 2f+1 fault tolerance model, so if you want to tolerate failure of a single node (failure includes communication issues), you will need at least 3 Zookeeper nodes and they should be deployed on separate hosts.  For Kafka, you will want at least 2 brokers and would need to set the minimum ISRs (in sync replicas) to 2.  Ideally you'd have 4 Kafka brokers.

2) In order for transactions to be processed, enough peers to satisfy the endorsement policy as well as the ordering service must be available / accessible.   Peers which cannot connect to the ordering service will catch up once they can reestablish connectivity.

Comment: Thanks Gari. That network is an example of course. It might be a silly question but , my case is that If internet connection goes down the network keeps working independently so, can there be 2 ordering service, each one for each organization?